# Basis of the sum and intersection of vector subspaces spanned by the given vector sets

Tags: linear-algebra

How would you find the basis of the sum and of the intersection of vector subspaces spanned by the following vector sets: A={(1,1,0,0), (0,1,1,0),(0,0,1,1)} and B={(1,0,1,0), (0,2,1,1), (1,2,1,2)}

I can think of creating a matrix A such that

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}

then reducing it to RREF and findign its basis which would be {(1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0)} hence dim(A+B)=4

dim(A) would be 3 as well as dim(B), so from the formula dim(A+B) = dim(A) = dim(B) - dim(A∩B) we have dim(A∩B) = 2. But I can't obtain such a result. I've tried to create a matrix X=(A|−B) and then find the basis of its nullspace but it looks nothing like a correct answer. Have i made a mistake in a previous calculations or another method should be used for finding the basis of the intersection?

Comment: Can you check out this youtube video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dlGmSaAWFU

Comment: i have watched that video, but i still obtain a weird result. vectors with 6 dimensions to be more precise

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that by "sum", you mean "union". In that case, you should keep in mind that the union of two subspaces is not, in general, a subspace. The union $U \cup W$ is only a subspace if $U \subseteq W$ or $W \subseteq U$, in which cases $W = U \cup W$ or $U = U \cup W$, respectively. I will leave it to you to verify this claim and to determine whether that is the case for your example.

The intersection of subspaces $U \cap W$ is always a subspace, and to find a basis for it, consider the conditions that a vector $v$ has to satisfy to belong in both $U$ and $W$. For your example, there must exist $x_1, x_2, x_3, y_1, y_2, y_3 \in \mathbb{F}$ such that

$$v = x_1 u_1 + x_2 u_2 + x_3 u_3 = y_1 w_1 + y_2 w_2 + y_3 w_3$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow 0 = x_1 u_1 + x_2 u_2 + x_3 u_3 + y_1 (-w_1) + y_2 (-w_2) + y_3 (-w_3)$$

where ${\rm Span} \{ u_1, u_2, u_3 \} = U$ and ${\rm Span} \{ w_1, w_2, w_3 \} = W$. From this, it is clear that

$$\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

belongs in the nullspace of the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
u_1 & u_2 & u_3 & -w_1 & -w_2 & -w_3
\end{pmatrix}$$

a basis for which can easily be determined using row-reduction.